# mixins: augmenting background-image property's value

Tags: css, mixins, less

Here is the following mixin:

```
.a () {background-image: url(one.png);}
```

now, I want `.b` inherits `.a` but it should add a second background image layer, eg:

```
.b {
    .a;                                 <-- import
    background-image: url(second.png);
}
```

will generate:

```
.b {
    background-image: url(one.png);
    background-image: url(second.png); /* wins */
}
```

and **not**

```
.b {
    background-image: url(one.png), url(second.png);
}
```

**which is what I would like...**

Is it possible to deal with this in LESS?

Comment: Isn't your second form not fully supported yet? (Just wondering, I don't think it is but I don't know.)

Comment: is that valid css? assigning to images to the background? the second one will cancel the first one

Comment: @Ibu : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image

Comment: @Ibu : and also http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in LESS, just not exactly as you have it written. In order to achieve what you are looking for you would have to set up the images as variables, like so:

```
@a:url('../images/img-a.png') top left repeat;
@b:url('../images/img-b.png') top left repeat;
```

Then when you are defining a class or id you would add the variables in like so:

```
.someClass {
    background:@a, @b;
}
```